Creating a circular react native component with complex styling
I've been digging into the react native world. Totally new to this area.
And was trying to create a button component. Where the button is kind of circular, and have a specific color, title that will be send to it by parameters.
The complex thing I'm trying to do is trying to achieve a type of inside linear effect to the button, where as into the attached image, it looks like a thin inside circle.
Please find attached image as an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

I've tried the following code:
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const HomeButton = ({ title, color }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: color }]}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 100,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    elevation: 5,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.5,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export default HomeButton;


This actually do create a circular button, but with very static color.
Tried also to install and use the following just to break the one color issue, but still didn't work:

npm install react-native-linear-gradient

Where the code became something like this:
const HomeButton = ({ title, colors }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
      <LinearGradient
        colors={colors}
        style={styles.gradient}
      >
        <View style={styles.innerCircle} />
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      </LinearGradient>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

Is the design actually doable? Any help please?

You could work it out using react native svg. I got the circles drawn; and now I'm trying to figure out how to shadowy parts https://snack.expo.dev/IgEBWl4HROQk8Q1VKCxkU

https://snack.expo.dev/-tJFe5NbStTxrdPOuJKXt

@PhantomSpooks man that's almost perfect, will try to edit the code until I have some waving in the inner lines.
Can you put this as answer so I can mark it?
Thank you!

I think I got it completely figured out; although at every re-render that shadowy thing changes

You can use react native svg. I started by creating a circle component
import { Circle, Path } from 'react-native-svg';
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { polarToCartesian, drawArc } from '../helpers/path';

const SvgCircle = ({
  color,
  isOutline,
  strokeWidth = 3,
  radius,
  center,
  // where shadow angle should start and end on circle
  shadowAnglePairs = [],
  isDebugging,
  // try playing around with this value
  steps = 5,
  // play around with these values to change how thick
  // the shadows can get
  xNoiseAmplitude = 1,
  yNoiseAmplitude = 2,
}) => {
  const pathRef = useRef(null);
  const [x, y] = center;
  const shadows = shadowAnglePairs.map(
    ([startAngleInDegrees, endAngleInDegrees]) => {
      const start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngleInDegrees);
      const end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngleInDegrees);
      const degreeStep = (endAngleInDegrees - startAngleInDegrees) / steps;
      // trace arc along circle
      let d = drawArc(x, y, radius, startAngleInDegrees, endAngleInDegrees);
      // get points along circle
      const stepPoints = Array(steps)
        .fill(null)
        .map((_, i) =>
          polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngleInDegrees + degreeStep * i)
        );
      // add noise along each point
      stepPoints.forEach(({ x, y }, i) => {
        d += `L ${x + Math.random() * xNoiseAmplitude} ${
          y - Math.random() * yNoiseAmplitude
        }`;
      });
      return { start, end, d, stepPoints };
    }
  );
  return (
    <>
      <Circle
        cx={x}
        cy={y}
        r={radius}
        fill={isOutline ? 'none' : color}
        stroke={isOutline ? color : 'none'}
      />
      {shadows.map(({ start, end, d, stepPoints }) => {
        return (
          <>
            <Path
              d={d}
              fill={color}
              stroke={color}
              ref={pathRef}
              strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
            />

            {
              // visual for start,end, & step points
              isDebugging &&
                [...stepPoints, start, end].map(({ x, y }, i) => (
                  <Circle
                    cx={x}
                    cy={y}
                    r={1}
                    fill={i > stepPoints.length - 1 ? 'red' : 'black'}
                  />
                ))
            }
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default SvgCircle;


Now you can draw your circles and decide where shadows should appear:
import { useState } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { colorManipulators } from '@phantom-factotum/colorutils';
import { Svg, Text, Circle, G, Path } from 'react-native-svg';
import SvgCircle from './SvgCircle';

const HomeButton = ({ title, color, onPress, size = 100, isDebugging }) => {
  const darkColor = colorManipulators.darkenColor(color, 0.5);
  const radius = size / 2;
  const center = [size / 2, size / 2];
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <View
        style={[
          styles.button,
          {
            borderRadius: size,
            width: size,
            height: size,
          },
        ]}>
        <Svg viewBox={`0 0 ${size} ${size}`}>
          {/*background color circle*/}
          <SvgCircle color={color} radius={radius * 0.85} center={center} />
          {/*outline rings*/}
          <SvgCircle
            color={darkColor}
            isOutline
            strokeWidth={1}
            radius={radius * 0.95}
            center={center}
            shadowAnglePairs={[
              [290, 360],
              [110, 180],
            ]}
            isDebugging={isDebugging}
          />
          <SvgCircle
            color={darkColor}
            isOutline
            strokeWidth={1}
            radius={radius * 0.9}
            center={center}
            angleOffset={2}
            shadowAnglePairs={[
              [300, 330],
              [120, 160],
            ]}
            isDebugging={isDebugging}
          />
          <SvgCircle
            color={darkColor}
            isOutline
            strokeWidth={1}
            radius={radius * 0.45}
            center={center}
            shadowAnglePairs={[
              [300, 330],
              [120, 160],
            ]}
            isDebugging={isDebugging}
          />
          <SvgCircle
            color={darkColor}
            isOutline
            strokeWidth={1}
            radius={radius * 0.5}
            center={center}
            shadowAnglePairs={[
              [300, 330],
              [120, 160],
            ]}
            isDebugging={isDebugging}
          />
          <Text
            fill="#fff"
            stroke="#fff"
            fontSize="20"
            x={center[0]}
            y={center[1]}
            textAnchor="middle"
            dominantBaseline="middle">
            {title}
          </Text>
        </Svg>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    bordersize: 100,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export default HomeButton;

Usage:
import { Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import LabeledSwitch from './components/LabeledSwitch';
import { useState } from 'react';
import SvgButton from './components/SvgButton';

export default function App() {
  const [isDebugging, setIsDebugging] = useState(false);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <LabeledSwitch
        value={isDebugging}
        onValueChange={setIsDebugging}
        label={'Toggle debugging'}
        style={{ width: '50%',margin:5 }}
      />
      <SvgButton
        color="lightblue"
        onPress={() => console.log('I was pressed')}
        title="Home"
        size={100}
        isDebugging={isDebugging}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

demo

Almost perfect man! Thank you

If you have a severely tricky component like in the example you provided you can try to download it as an image and create a button in the following way:
interface Props extends TouchableOpacityProps {
  title: string;
}

const HomeButton: React.FC<Props> = ({title, style, ...restProps}) => (
  <TouchableOpacity style={[{alignSelf: 'center'}, style]} {...restProps}>
    <ImageBackground
      source={require('@assets/images/button.jpeg')}
      style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', width: 100, height: 100, padding: 10}}>
      <Text style={{color: 'white', textDecorationLine: 'underline', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>{title}</Text>
    </ImageBackground>
 </TouchableOpacity>
)

Gif how does work example from the code snippet

Hello Anastasiia, I thought about this path, but the issue will be if I I have 9 buttons, I'll have to add 9 images into the project. Keeping that as last resort.
But looks like this is what's going to be
